# How to apply a multidimensional look up table to a color image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, lookup-tables

For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that the image has two rows and four columns, and pixel colors are represented by a triplet of intensity levels (intensity is quantized to five different integer values). I want to transform such color image into a single-channel image through a 3D look up table by using the intensity levels of each pixel as indices. This toy example can be implemented as follows:

```
import numpy as np
levels = 5
rows, columns, channels = 2, 4, 3

lut = np.arange(levels**channels).reshape([levels for n in range(channels)])
np.random.seed(0)
img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=levels, size=(rows, columns, channels))
```

I'm aware that I can hardcode the indexing like this:

```
red = img[:, :, 0]
green = img[:, :, 1]
blue = img[:, :, 2]
indexed = lut[red, green, blue]
```

The code above can be generalized to work with multi spectral images:

```
indexed = lut[[img[:, :, i] for i in range(channels)]]
```

Both approaches yield the same result:

```
In [931]: indexed
Out[931]: 
array([[103,  91,  89,   4],
       [ 55,  30,  48,  15]])
```

**My question**: Is there a more elegant way to obtain the same result? More concretely, I'm looking for a NumPy function that splits a color image (3D array) into a list of its chromatic channels (2D arrays). Alternatively I've thought that the transformation could be carried out through matplotlib using `lut` as a colormap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this:

```
red, green, blue = img.transpose()

lut[red, green, blue].transpose()
```

what you are looking for?

The `img.transpose()` needed for rearranging the axes expected for channel unpack.

For an arbitrary number of channels:

```
lut[tuple(img.transpose())].transpose()
```

Comment: So you want to avoid creating the `red`, `green`, `blue` variables?

Comment: `lut[tuple(img.T)].T` yields the expected result. Is there a way to avoid double transposition?